# Efficient Method of finding common files between two given paths in Python

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I have written code to find out common files between two given folders (paths) accounting for all levels of sub folders if present.

Please suggest if there is a more efficient method. It's taking too long if folders with many levels of subfolders are given.

```
def findCommonDeep(self,path1,path2):
    commonfiles = []

    for (dirpath1, dirname1, filenames1) in os.walk(path1):
        for file in filenames1:
            for (dirpath2, dirname2, filenames2) in os.walk(path2):
                if (file in filenames2 and isfile(join(dirpath2, file))):
                        commonfiles.append(file)

    print(commonfiles)
```

and calling this function with paths, like shown below:

```
findCommonDeep("/home/naseer/Python", "/home/naseer/C")
```

I understand that if I store a list of all files for any given path the speed of execution can be reduced. but I guess that will run out of memory. Please guide me in approaching to this more efficiently.

Comment: What do you mean by *common files*?

Comment: @RoadRunner files with same name and extension

Comment: @NaseerMohammad then just create a dicitonary with the key of <filename>.<extension> and the value will be a tuple containing the frequency of the file present in two file paths. If the frequency is greather than in both case, the file is common.

Comment: This will increase the complexity more I guess. To add each file to dictionary have to iterate over it!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use generator expression to transform the output of `os.walk` into two sets and use set intersection to efficiently identify the common paths.

```
import os
def findCommonDeep(path1, path2):
    files1 = set(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), path1) for root, _, files in os.walk(path1) for file in files)
    files2 = set(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), path2) for root, _, files in os.walk(path2) for file in files)
    return files1 & files2
```

To reduce code duplication in the code above, you can use another list comprehension:

```
import os
def findCommonDeep(path1, path2):
    return set.intersection(*(set(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), path) for root, _, files in os.walk(path) for file in files) for path in (path1, path2)))
```

And if you're looking for just the common file names rather than common path names, you can make the generator expression output just the file names instead:

```
def findCommonDeep(path1, path2):
    return set.intersection(*(set(file for _, _, files in os.walk(path) for file in files) for path in (path1, path2)))
```

This is more efficient because it takes advantage of Python's set intersection operation, which has an average [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) of `O(min(len(n), len(m))`, whereas your code with 2 nested loops always takes `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I think it is helpful to point out why @blhsing's solution is faster.

In your question, @NaseerMohammad, the code iterates over `dirpath2` for _every file_ in `dirpath1` because of the nested `for` loops! So the code is doing the same work for every file in `dirpath1`. @blhsing's solution only iterates over each directory once.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks. It is working faster. Could you please elaborate your explanation about your answer

Comment: @NaseerMohammad Not too sure which parts of my answer you need more elaboration on. If you are unsure of how Python's list comprehension/generator expression works, you can refer to [list comprehension's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more details. I think I've explained the rest of the logic in my answer already though. Let me know which specific part you still need more explanations on.

Comment: @blhsing your answer is faster but its incomplete. I am having error

Comment: @blhsing My code is giving output as 11 files.Your code is producing 1 file as output

Comment: @NaseerMohammad I see. Are you looking for just the common file names? My code assumes that you're looking for common path names as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177149/discussion-between-naseer-mohammad-and-blhsing).

Comment: @NaseerMohammad I just updated my answer with a solution that outputs just the common file names. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way in Python 3.5+ is to use the built-in `os.path.commonpath` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonpath)).

```py
import os
common_path = os.path.commonpath([path1, path2]))
```

An alternative if you want to use only `pathlib.Path` (based on intersection of the different parents, and inspired from accepted solution):

```py
from pathlib import Path

def common_parent(p1: Path, p2: Path) -> Path:
    """Find the common parent of two paths"""
    common_paths = sorted(set(p1.parents).intersection(set(p2.parents)))
    if not common_paths:
        raise ValueError(f"No common parent found between {p1} and {p2}")
    return common_paths[-1]
```

... or possibly (code a bit longer but execution might be faster):

```py
def common_parent(p1: Path, p2: Path) -> Path:
    """Find the common parent of two paths"""
    parents_p2 = set(p2.parents)
    for parent in list(p1.parents)[::-1]:
        if parent in parents_p2:
            return parent
    raise ValueError(f"No common parent found between {p1} and {p2}")
```