# removing back dots dir from path's prefix

Tags: python, pathlib, os.path

I have two paths.

`path1 =  /users/fida/data_lake/data/archived/09142023`

`path2 = /users/fida/data_lake/data/localpublished/SPTTES/End_to_End_Edit_Schedule/2022-08-03_11_22_03.kp`

Output Im trying to get after combining both path is:
`/users/fida/data_lake/data/archived/09142023/localpublished/SPTTES/End_to_End_Edit_Schedule/2022-08-03_11_22_03.kp`

I have tried `os.path.relpath` but I get dots in the prefix which mess the path.

`..\..\localpublished\SPTTES\End_to_End_Edit_Schedule\2022-08-03_11_22_03.kp`

Comment: That's what a relative path _is_. Why do you use `relpath` if it's not what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the "back dots" can be done by using the second parameter of [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath). It defaults to `os.curdir`, therefore you get the "back dots".

---

You could use [`os.path.commonpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonpath) (introduced in Python 3.5) to determine the common parent path.

Next, you leverage the second argument of [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) to get the relative path of `path2` at the common parent path.

And finally, you join `path1` with the relative path of `path2` using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

```py
import os

path1 = "/users/fida/data_lake/data/archived/09142023"
path2 = "/users/fida/data_lake/data/localpublished/S/S/2022-08-03_11_22_03.kp"

common_path = os.path.commonpath([path1, path2])

relative_path2 = os.path.relpath(path2, common_path)

new_path = os.path.join(path1, relative_path2)

print(new_path)
```

---

If you prefer to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), then you could also leverage [Jean-François T's `common_parent` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76419489/42659).

[`pathlib.Path.relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.is_relative_to) is the equivalent of `os.path.relpath`. Joining the paths is done by simply using a slash (`/`). `new_path` is a `pathlib.Path` object here and can be parsed to a string using `str()`.

```py
from pathlib import Path

path1 = Path("/users/fida/data_lake/data/archived/09142023")
path2 = Path("/users/fida/data_lake/data/localpublished/S/S/2022-08-03_11_22_03.kp")

def common_parent(p1: Path, p2: Path) -> Path:

    """ Find the common parent of two paths

        The author of function common_parent is Jean-François T. and
        the original can be found here 
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/76419489/42659 """

    common_paths = sorted(set(p1.parents).intersection(set(p2.parents)))
    if not common_paths:
        raise ValueError(f"No common parent found between {p1} and {p2}")
    return common_paths[-1]

common_path = common_parent(path1, path2)

relative_path2 = path2.relative_to(common_path)

new_path = path1 / relative_path2

print(new_path)  # parse with `str()` if necessary
```

---

Note: `path2` was shortened in both example to avoid horizontal scrolling on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask for `relpath()` ask for `abspath()` if you want the absolute path not the relative path.